# Getting source maps on staing/production env rails 5.2 webpacker gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

Tried following guides from

- https://survivejs.com/webpack/building/source-maps/
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

But didn't get it working on deployed app, I'm using

> rails 5.2.2
>
> webpacker 3.5.5

What's the proper way to enable source maps so I can debug js packs code on staging/production environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should able to specify the source map strategy using the Webpacker config API as follows:

```js
// config/webpack/production.js

const environment = require('./environment')

environment.config.merge({ devtool: 'source-map' }) // or whatever type you want

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```